# Getting the elements of an equivalence class, and total number of equivalence classes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, equivalence-relations

$$\text{Let } A = \{1,2,3,4,...,271\}. \text{Define the relation $R$ on $A \times A$ by:}$$

$$ \text{for any $(a,b)$, $(c,d) \in A \times A$,  $(a,b)R(c,d)$ iff $a + b = c+ d$.}$$

$\text{(a) List all the elements of $[(3,3)]$, the equivalence class of $(3,3)$.}$

$\text{(b) How many equivalence classes does $R$ have? Explain.}$

For part (a) I'm not sure how to get the elements of $[(3,3)]$ when there are two elements in the set. It wouldn't just be every set where 3 is the first element, right? i.e. $(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),...,(3,271)$

For part (b), $|A \times A| = 271 \times 271 = 73441$. So would the number of equivalence classes be $73441 + 1 = 73442$, considering the empty set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (a), the equivalence class of $(3,3)$ is the set of pairs $(a,b)$ such that $(3,3) \mathbin{R} (a,b)$, namely
$$\{ (a,b) \in A \times A : 3+3 = a+b \}$$
This is certainly not the set $\{ (3,1),(3,2),\dots,(3,271) \}$.

For (b), you need to consider what values $a+b$ can take for $(a,b) \in A \times A$. Each equivalence class of $R$ corresponds with a unique value of $a+b$, so the number of possible values that $a+b$ can take is equal to the number of equivalence classes of $R$.

Comment: I understand (a) now, but I don't see how I could solve (b) by hand. For every $a + b$ the number of equivalence classes is going to vary.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "for every $a+b$ the number of equivalence classes is going to vary". For each possible value $k$ that $a+b$ can take, there is a unique $R$-equivalence class whose elements are exactly those pairs of elements of $A$ that sum to $k$.

Comment: If my calculations are correct, the number of equivalence classes for each $(a,b)$ should be $(a+b)-1$. i.e. for $(3,3)$ the number of equivalence classes would be $(3+3)-1 = 6-1 = 5$. Summing every equivalence class up would take a long time, without using a program, which is why I don't understand the methodology to do this by hand.

Comment: @qbuffer: I think you need to look carefully at the definitions. You're confusing "the number of equivalence classes of $R$" with "the number of elements in a fixed equivalence class $[(a,b)]$".

Comment: Wouldn't it just be $271$ equivalence classes then?

Comment: @qbuffer: Not quite. How many possible values can $a+b$ take if $1 \le a \le 271$ and $1 \le b \le 271$?

Comment: It would be all the values from the range $2$ to $542$. So the number of equivalence classes are $271 + 271 - 1 = 541$?

Comment: There you go. (Of course now you need to turn that into a proof.)